# passing commandline parameter to .sh (shell) file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I am executing shell file like this in terminal:

```
./cherrypicker.sh input.txt
```

input.txt contains input text.

My purpose is to pass `input text` directly as command line argument from web interface

I checked cherrypicker.sh file, to get some clue. it has

```
tools/pos/pos.sh tools/pos $1 > $1.pos 2> /dev/null
```

If `$1` would have been text from `input.txt` then I could have passes text directly. But when I do `echo $1` it give `input.txt`.

I could not understand what is `>` indicates here and also `2` and `/dev/null`

Any explaination would be much appreciable. I checked about .sh file but articles says it's shell file equavalent to .bat file

Cherrypicker.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "running stanford pos tagger..."
tools/pos/pos.sh tools/pos $1 > $1.pos 2> /dev/null

echo $1.pos

echo "running stanford ner tagger..."
tools/ner/ner.sh tools/ner $1 > $1.ner 2> /dev/null

echo "running charniak parsing..."
java MakeCharniakInput $1
tools/charniak-parser/PARSE/parseIt -l300 tools/charniak-parser/DATA/EN/ $1.charniakIN > $1.charniak

echo "running minipar parsing..."
tools/minipar/pdemo/pdemo -p tools/minipar/data/ < $1 > $1.minipar

echo "detecting mentions..."
java MentionDetection $1
tools/crf++/crf_test -m modelmd $1.crf > $1.pred
java CreateNPSpan $1 $1.pred


# if [[  $1 = "mp" ]]
# then
#   echo "creating feature file...."
#       java -cp .:edu.mit.jwi.jar CherryPick mp raw.txt
#       echo "classifying clusters using $1 model....."
#       tools/svmmentionpair/svm_classify raw.txt.mpsvm modelmp raw.txt.mppred
#       java MakeCluster raw.txt raw.txt.mppred
#   elif  [[ ( $1 = "mr" ) || ( $1 = "cr" )  ]]
#   then
    echo "creating feature file...."
    java -cp .:edu.mit.jwi.jar CherryPick cr $1
    echo "classifying clusters using cr joint model....."
    tools/svmrank/svm_classify $1 modelrank > $1.entities
#   else
#       echo "cannot classify clusters using *mysterious* model....."
#   fi


echo "creating output....."
java MakeResponse $1
```

Comment: `cherrypicker.sh` expects as input a filename, not some text. As the various programs used in this script also expect a filename and cannot be given some text directly (in particular "java"), you first need to create a file containing your text, then pass it to the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Command:**

```
   tools/pos/pos.sh tools/pos $1 > $1.pos 2> /dev/null
```

***Explanation:***

```
tools/pos/pos.sh  - script

tools/pos         - Positional argument 1 for pos.sh

$1                - Positional argument 2 for pos.sh

$1.pos            - Is a file which will hold the standard output of pos.sh

/dev/null         - is a null file which will hold standard error
```

The tools/pos/pos.sh takes two postional arguments in this case `tools/pos` & `$1(input.txt)` does its work

and redirects the standard output of `tools/pos/pos.sh` to file `$1.pos(input.txt.pos)` ,the part `> $1.pos` of the command does this  and

the part `2> /dev/null` of the above command redirects the standard error to `/dev/null`

Comment: thanks dear, can you please tell me in `./cherrypicker.sh input.txt` how can I directly pass the input text rather text file name. I have edited the question with shell file content

Comment: The short answer is: You can't, you need to create a file containing your text and pass the name of this file.

Comment: As @Lars Noschinski suggested you can't pass the contents of the file and you don't have to , the ./cherrypicker.sh expects the file name as arguments and the cherrypicker uses this file name inturn to pass the file name as argument to other command and scripts used within the cherrypicker.sh , passing the contents of file name to cherrypicker.sh will break the script

Comment: @Ram and Lars: thanks, but issue is I am getting input from gearman worker as a "string text". can I do like `echo <input text> > input.txt` when ever I get request to proceed. and at the end executing `rm input.*` to remove generated files, so that next time fresh input is considered?

Comment: @user123 yeah you can do `echo "$stringText" > input.txt` before running the `cherrypicker.sh input.txt` and you don't have to remove the input.txt, since the single `>` redirection will overwrite the input.txt with contents of `$stringText` each time        `echo "$stringText"  > input.txt` is executed. Does this help?

Comment: @Ram: yeah, but executing cherrypicker also create few more files like input.txt.pos, input.txt.ner etc. which needs to be removed.

Comment: so can I do like creating a `shell.sh` file which contains all command we discusses that is `$stringText" > input.txt` `./cherrypicker.sh input.txt` `reading and storing cherrypicker result` `rm input.*` . And executing it when I receive input text from gearman worker?

Comment: @user123 yeah you can do it the way you said by wrapping the cherrypicker.sh in a script.. , Have you tried does the approach work?

Answer (score 2):

1) > and 2> manipulate standard output and standard error stream redirection respectively, so your output goes into $1.pos and error is redirected to /dev/null (discarded)

2) if you want to feed the content of a file as input, then you can redirect the file as input, e.g.:

```
tools/pos/pos.sh tools/pos < $1 > $1.pos 2> /dev/null
```

or through a pipe:

```
cat $1 | tools/pos/pos.sh tools/pos > $1.pos 2> /dev/null
```

3) if you want the file contents as an argument (I hope input.txt is just one line), then try this:

```
tools/pos/pos.sh tools/pos `cat $1` > $1.pos 2> /dev/null
```

or you can try xargs to execute your command once per line:

```
cat $1 | xargs -I myargs tools/pos/pos.sh tools/pos myargs >> $1.pos 2> /dev/null
```

here >> means standard output is appended to the same file.

Comment: thanks dear, can you please tell me in `./cherrypicker.sh input.txt` how can I directly pass the input text rather text file name. I have edited the question with shell file content

Comment: use xargs for invoking your command for each line:
cat input.txt | xargs ./cherrypicker.sh

Comment: btw, you can lookup all this information in a manual, like: "man xargs"
it is a steep learning, but it is worth it (Unix interface hasn't changed for many years).